# trouble with a php form

Tags: php, forms, methods, get, action

I met a trouble with a form.

In fact I have a php dynbamic page which has 1 parameter (and id), I'm trying to get an other parameter, so I have this fom:

```
<form action="index.php?p=employee-monitoring&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ; ?>" method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>CHOISIR UNE DATE</legend>
<label>Date:</label>

<input type="date" name="date" onblur="form.submit()" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

But when I choose a date it redirection me to index.php and there is no parameter on the date, for example it redirect me to this page /index.php?date=

I do not understand what did I wrong have done.

receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field and remove `&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ; ?>` from the action attribute.

```
<form action="index.php?p=employee-monitoring" method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>CHOISIR UNE DATE</legend>
<label>Date:</label>

<input type="date" name="date" onblur="form.submit()" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ; ?>" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

Actually, you should pass `p=employee-monitoring` the same way:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<fieldset>
<legend>CHOISIR UNE DATE</legend>
<label>Date:</label>

<input type="date" name="date" onblur="form.submit()" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="employee-monitoring" />


</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. But sometimes the way of passing var to url directly has worked for me, why it does not take it from url parameter and why should we submit them to the hidden input of type?

Comment: I can't find any reference online, but it's because you can't have $_GET variables BOTH in action and in form data sent to the server. Notice that you can now use `method="post"` instead, which is safer.

Comment: yeah i know but it is only for the intranet and this form only will display information for logfile for the selected date so there is no way to make any injection to the databse. Moreover I use a mysql_real_escape_string on the var that is read

Comment: Then it's ok with $_GET i guess :) just remember to don't mix up `action` and form values

Comment: excuse me my english level is not verry good to understand the meaning of mix up words, can you please explain it to me.   Kind Regards SP

Comment: My english is bad either :) i mean that if you pass something via `method="get"` it will be added to the url, this way `index.php?variable=value&another-variable=another-value` etc. But if your action url is `index.php?already-some-variable=value` , the part from ? to the right will be deleted. It's ok only if you use `method="post"`.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you verry much for your precisions. Receive My Utmost Respect